# Best practice - Local notification ID

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

What is the best practice to work with local notifications? There is an assumption of frequently updating scheduled notifications; retrieving them using `userInfo`. Is `arc4random()` good enough as ID generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a unique identifier, I would create a UUID like this:

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *uuidString = [(NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid) autorelease];
CFRelease(uuid);
NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuidString);
```